# My Java Code Throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, exception, null, automation

I'm writing a Java code that would run a simple automation scenario in Chrome or Firefox - depending on the user's input. It starts running (opens a browser), but then throws java.lang.NullPointerException. I thought then the null I assigned the driver variable would later be overridden, but it isn't. How can this be fixed? Thanks!

```
package com.selenium;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // environment variable
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\libs\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Automation\\libs\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = null;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 for Chrome or 2 for Firefox " + option);
        if (option == 1)
        {
            WebDriver driver1= new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if 
        (option == 2)
        {
            WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("Please enter a correct number " + option);

        String baseURL = "https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=eu";

        driver.get(baseURL);

        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        userName.sendKeys("Yan");

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        password.sendKeys("123456");

        WebElement rememberCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.id("rememberUn"));
        rememberCheckbox.click();

        WebElement bLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("Login"));
        bLogin.click();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show stacktrace

Comment: False:  WebDriver driver1= new FirefoxDriver();  Right: driver = newFireFoxDriver(),

Comment: You are not setting the variable `driver` to anything else than `null`. How did you expect that it would be "overridden"? Note that you are creating new variables `driver1` and `driver2`, but these of course do not have any effect on the variable `driver`.

Comment: You just create new drivers inside your if{}. Just assign like

if (option == 1)
        {
            driver1= new FirefoxDriver();
        }

Answer (score 4):

driver is never assigned, you just create new drivers. Change:

```
    if (option == 1)
    {
        WebDriver driver1= new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else if 
    (option == 2)
    {
        WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

to:

```
    if (option == 1)
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else if 
    (option == 2)
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `driver.get(baseURL);` throws. In bodies of your conditional statements you are creating new variables (driver1, driver2) and never use them. Please assign value to previously declared `driver` variable.

```
if (option == 1)
{
   WebDriver driver1= new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

Would become

```
if (option == 1)
{
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

And

```
else if (option == 2)
{
   WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Would become

```
else if (option == 2)
{
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line  `driver.get(baseURL)`

You call a method on this Object, but this object is still `null` at this point.

That's why the NullPointerException is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You have to take care of a lot of facts in your code as follows:

1. Keep the configuration of `environment variable` as in `System.setProperty` with in particular `for()` loops.
2. Keep the line `scanner.nextInt()` after printing the text `Please enter 1 for Chrome or 2 for Firefox`.
3. Once you complete using the scanner instance close it to prevent future `Resource Leakage`.
4. Keep the name of the `WebDriver` instance as `driver` throughout your `Automation Framework` scope.
5. In your code, you have declared `WebDriver` instance as `null` in the beginning and moving forward you were trying either to initiate `driver1` or `driver2` again. Hence you faced **`java.lang.NullPointerException`**
6. Here is the sample code block as per your requirement which will use Mozilla Firefox, browse to url `https://login.salesforce.com/`, provide username & password and finally click on `Log In` button:

   ```
   package demo;

   import java.util.Scanner;

   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class Q45482474 {

       public static void main(String[] args) {


       WebDriver driver = null;

       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please enter 1 for Chrome or 2 for Firefox : ");
       int option = scanner.nextInt();
       scanner.close();
       if (option == 1)
       {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
           driver= new FirefoxDriver();
       }
       else if 
       (option == 2)
       {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
           driver = new ChromeDriver();
       }
       else 
           System.out.println("Please enter a correct number.");

       String baseURL = "https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=eu";

       driver.get(baseURL);

       WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
       userName.sendKeys("Yan");

       WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
       password.sendKeys("123456");

       WebElement rememberCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.id("rememberUn"));
       rememberCheckbox.click();

       WebElement bLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("Login"));
       bLogin.click();

       }

   }
   ```
7. On executing this program you will observe the following output on the console:

   ```
   Please enter 1 for Chrome or 2 for Firefox : 
   1
   1501764400779   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
   1501764400792   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:35604
   1501764401293   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
   1501764421881   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 48303
   Aug 03, 2017 6:17:02 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
   INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.